# How to solve "java.net.SocketException: Connection reset" when running confluent-hub install

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

when i running this command

```
/root/heraldhealth/softwares/confluent-5.2.1/bin/confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-datagen:latest
```

on my centos7 machine , i am getting this error below :

```
 Running in a "--no-prompt" mode
 java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

 Error: Unknown error
```

Though command like /bin/confluent start is working fine

i am following [this link](https://docs.confluent.io/current/quickstart/ce-quickstart.html#ce-quickstart)

expected output:

```
Running in a "--no-prompt" mode
...
Completed
```

actual output: error shown above.

Comment: i checked https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-docker-images/issues/731#issuecomment-490456098 but it is a solution related to Docker container , can someone simplify it for my CentOs 7 machine